# How do I group parent child entities using java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to group some entities putting the children on the parent..

```
@Entity 
public class JournalEntry {
    Integer id;
    String message;
    Integer parentId;        
}
```

The data transfer object would look like this...

```
public class JournalDTO {
    public JournalDTO (Integer id, String message, List<JournalDTO> childEntries) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.childEntries = childEntries;
    }
    Integer id;
    String message;
    List<JournalDTO> childEntries;
}
```

So I hope to end up with a List, which do not have a parent ID, so are top level and then they would have a group of child entities, and within these child entities they may also have child entities. Is there a way of doing this. 
My idea was to first get all the top level entries as follows..

```
List<JournalEntry> journalEntries = service.fetchJournalEntries();
List<JournalEntry> topLevel = journalEntries.stream().filter(e -> null==e.getParentId()).collect(toList());
journalEntries.removeAll(topLevel);
List<JournalDTO> journalDTOs = topLevel.stream()
                            .map(tl -> new JournalDTO(tl.getId(), tl.getMessage(), new ArrayList<JournalDTO>()))
                            .collect(toList());
```

then I group the remaining entries by the parent ID..

```
Map<Integer, List<JournalEntry>> childMap = journalEntries.stream().collect(groupingBy(Integer::getParentId));
```

I can then iterate through this map and add the childEntities to the parent entity but this would only give me the second level, I would then have to ensure there is no children of children etc... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you explain more with one example. I didn't understand what do you want to do? because you write some code which works except last one. it is not true because you type getParentId for integer (fix it too).

Comment: getter/setters omitted, so getParentId would return the integer ID of journal entry. So basically I need collection of journal DTO's which can have a collection of journal DTO's as child entries property and each of those can have a collection of journal DTO's as child entries and so on, parentId identifies entry as child of entry with id equal to parentId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What an interesting problem. First I've defined a method for simplicity:

```
private static JournalDTO toDTO(JournalEntry entry) {
    return new JournalDTO(entry.getId(), entry.getMessage(), new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Than I defined some small computational `Map`(s) that would help me search fast:

```
    Map<Integer, JournalEntry> identity = entries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(JournalEntry::getId, Function.identity()));

    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = entries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    x -> x.getParentId() == null ? -1 : x.getParentId(),
                    Collectors.mapping(JournalEntry::getId, Collectors.toSet())));
```

The first one should be obvious, it holds an ID paired with a `JournalEntry`.

The second one holds `parentId`s to a Set of ids. Basically:

```
-1 == 1 // -1 meaning it has no parents
 1 == 2 // 1 has a child with id 2
 2 == 3, 4 // 2 has two children with id 3 and 4
 4 == 5, 6 // ...
```

If you think about - this is how I find an entire "family" for example (let me know if there are further details required here).

The rest is simple code with a recursive method:

```
// get those that have no parents first
Set<Integer> ids = map.get(-1);

// this is the ultimate result 
List<JournalDTO> all = new ArrayList<>();

// for each entity with no parents, start searching in the map
ids.forEach(x -> {
     JournalDTO parentDTO = toDTO(identity.get(x));
     recursive(x, map, identity, parentDTO);
     all.add(parentDTO);
});
```

And of course the most important part:

```
private static void recursive(
        Integer parentId,
        Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map,
        Map<Integer, JournalEntry> identity,
        JournalDTO journalDTO) {

    Set<Integer> childrenIds = map.get(parentId);

    if (childrenIds != null && !childrenIds.isEmpty()) {
        childrenIds.forEach(x -> {
            JournalDTO childDTO = toDTO(identity.get(x));
            journalDTO.getChildEntries().add(childDTO);
            recursive(x, map, identity, childDTO);
        });
    }
}
```

I've tested this for a fairly simple case (the one with `==`) and seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I have a usecase similar to this except 1) my List<JournalEntry> contains duplicate records i.e., id property can repeat in multiple rows and 2) List<JournalEntry> does not contains any records whose parent is null. Although I trying to solve it my own but any help would be appreciated..